# Clearing JS response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a call to an API. The API returns a list of results. When it does so - the response is fed into an object which I then use to iterate through and display them.

Here is the function which does that:

```
    var getAvailability = () => {
        if (chosenData.hotel == "") {
            showError("Please select a location before booking.");
            $timeout(() => LTBNavService.setTab('location'), 50);
            return;
        }

        searchResponse = {};
        console.log(searchResponse);
        WebAPI.getHotelAvailability(genSearchObject()).then((data) => {
            searchResponse = data;
            $timeout(() => $('[data-tab-content] .search-btn').first().focus(), 50);
            generateRoomTypeObject(searchResponse);
        }, (data) => searchResponse.error = data.data.errors[0].error);

    };
```

The Problem:
The old results are still displayed until the new set of results are available. This causes a flicker and a delay which is a bad user experience.

The solution:(which i need help with)
What is the best possible way of handling this problem? Ideally, I would like to reset/clear the search response. As in, the new results are delivered and the old ones are cleared. Is this possible from within the getAvailability function?

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Where is your state?

Comment: Assuming `generateRoomTypeObject()` is what's drawing the results to the DOM, you could simply call `generateRoomTypeObject({})` before making the ajax call.

Comment: Thanks - that helped me fix the the problem in the end! +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Solution:**

Thanks to @Daniel Beck for his suggestion to call the generateRoomTypeObject function and feed it an empty object - +1'd his comment.

This triggered an undefined error in my generateRoomTypeObject function where i was running a few length checks(makes sense, because the object was empty - so there was nothing to do length checks on).

I handled the error by handling the undefined exception and setting the searchResponse to an empty object.

```
  var generateRoomTypeObject = (searchResponse) => {
    var ratePlans = searchResponse.ratePlans,
        errors = searchResponse.error,
        roomTypes = [],
        ignoreBiggerRooms = false;
    rawRoomsObjs = [];
    if (angular.isUndefined(errors)) {
        // Iterate over the rate plan
        if(ratePlans === undefined){   
            //generateRoomTypeObject -- Handle undefined by creating new object
            searchResponse =  {}
        }else{
              for (var i = 0; i < ratePlans.length; i++) {
            var ratePlan = ratePlans[i],
                rooms = ratePlan.rooms;
            // Iterate over the rooms and add rooms to room object. Also keep a list of room types.
            for (var j = 0; j < rooms.length; j++) {
                //Stuff here
            }
        }
    }
}
```